# @ngx-translate/core 9.0.0 with Angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have question related to `ngx-translate.`

I was using 7th version and updated to 9th.
I'm not able to import such things with angular 5.2

```
import * as ngxTranslateCore from '@ngx-translate/core';
import * as ngxTranslateCoreService from '@ngx- 
translate/core/src/translate.service';
import * as ngxTranslateCoreIndex from '@ngx-translate/core/index';
```

> ERROR in
>   ./src/app/pages/campaign-task-page/services/plugins.service.ts [0]
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ngx-translate/core/index' in
>   'E:\Sandboxes\Marketing.Automation\code\ng-ma-app\src\app\pages\campaign-task-page\services'
>   [0] ERROR in
>   ./src/app/pages/campaign-task-page/services/plugins.service.ts [0]
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '@ngx-translate/core/src/translate.service' in
>   'E:\Sandboxes\Marketing.Automation\code\ng-ma-app\src\app\pages\campaign-task-page\services'

Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: did you try adding the module in app.module.ts

Comment: `TranslateService` is now available in v9 as `import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';`

Comment: You may need to review the code, as there are many changes underwent from v7 to v9.